# Navbar links not getting smaller

Tags: html, css, image, navbar

I am having an issue with my navbar, once I make the browser tab smaller, the text stays the same size but the logo gets smaller and smaller and disappears. How can I make it so everything gets smaller? If any more information is needed I will provide them. Here are some examples of my problem.
[100% width page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffKbK.png) vs [Page made smaller for smaller screens for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfV4t.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


/* custom scroll bar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

::selection {
  background: rgb(0, 123, 255, 0.3);
}

.content {
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}


/* Nav start*/

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 25px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .menu-list {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menu-list li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-list li a:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.about {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.about .title {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.about p {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.menu-list .cancel-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1230px) {
  .content {
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .content {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .content {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 868px) {
  body.disabled {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .icon.hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #222;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbar.show .menu-list {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list li {
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  .navbar .menu-list li a {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  .navbar.show .menu-list li a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .navbar .logo a {
    font-size: 27px;
  }
}

.cta {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.cta:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}


/* Nav end*/
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/index.html"><img src="images/logo-villa-dor.jpg" width="100%"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <div class="icon cancel-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
      </div>
      <li><a href="/fireplaces.html">Fireplaces</a></li>
      <li><a href="/floorings.html">Floorings</a></li>
      <li><a href="/iron_works.html">IronWorks</a></li>
      <li><a href="/ornaments.html">Ornaments</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Woodwork.html">Woodwork</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Radiators.html">Radiators</a></li>
      <li><a href="/luminairy.html">Luminary</a></li>
      <li><a href="/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="icon menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using **@media** wrong.

```
@media (max-width: 868px)
```

indicates that these styles will be applied when it has a max width of 868px. So for small screens you need to decrease the font-size in there.

```
@media (max-width: 868px) {
    .navbar .menu-list li a{
         font-size: 16px; // for example
         margin-left: -100%;
         transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 
         1.55);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mh that doesnt seem to be fixing it, here i made a recording to make it more clear of the situation. https://youtu.be/drRPmEHCVsQ so here as you can see the text doesnt ajust, only the image does. Ive tried your awnser but it hast fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues in your styles that have proven to be problematic for your design. For sake of demonstrating the `media-queries` behavior, I have deleted all your `media queries` and made just one that points to your `<ul>` and your **logo**, which appears to be the focal point in this example.

Please see the CSS changes I made between `/* Media Start` & `/* Media End */`. Also, my suggestion, if you are flexing the navbar, would be to use `display: flex;` instead of `inline-flex`. Then you can add `justify-content: space-between;` to properly align your **nav** components. Next, this is just out of preference, but I wouldn't suggest spacing your `li's` with `margin-left` because then you get left margin on your "Fireplaces" `<li>` which is just unnecessary margin. I used `gap: 10px;` as an alternative.

Please see the changes to the logo as well. With this correct structure for your `media-queries`, I believe it will be much easier for you to manipulate. Without being able to see your image or the size of it, it's challenging to give you an exact `height & width` so adjust the `25px` around as necessary. Finally, setting `font-sizes` on logos or images won't be useful, unless there is a text element within the containing parent div of the image or logo.

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/* custom scroll bar */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 10px;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     background: #f1f1f1;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background: #888;
}
 ::selection{
     background: rgb(0,123,255,0.3);
}
 .content{
     max-width: 1250px;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 0 30px;
}
/* Nav start*/
 .navbar{
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 2;
     padding: 25px 0;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
     background-color: black;
}
 .navbar.sticky{
     background: black;
     padding: 10px 0;
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
 .navbar .content{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
 .navbar .logo a{
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 30px;
     font-weight: 600;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .navbar .menu-list{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     gap: 10px;
}
 .menu-list li{
     list-style: none;
}
 .menu-list li a{
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: 500;
     text-decoration: none;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
 .menu-list li a:hover{
     color: #007bff;
}
 .banner{
     height: 100vh;
     background-position: center;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
 .about{
     padding: 30px 0;
}
 .about .title{
     font-size: 38px;
     font-weight: 700;
}
 .about p{
     padding-top: 20px;
     text-align: justify;
}
 .icon{
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: none;
}
 .menu-list .cancel-btn{
     position: absolute;
     right: 30px;
     top: 20px;
}
 .cta {
     padding: 9px 25px;
     background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
     border: none;
     border-radius: 50px;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
 .cta:hover {
     background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 0.8);
}
/* Nav end*/

/* Media Start */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul.menu-list li a {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
  }
}

/* Media End */
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="/index.html" ><img src="images/logo-villa-dor.jpg" width="100%"></a>
          </div>
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <div class="icon cancel-btn">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
              <li><a href="/fireplaces.html">Fireplaces</a></li>
              <li><a href="/floorings.html">Floorings</a></li>
              <li><a href="/iron_works.html">IronWorks</a></li>
              <li><a href="/ornaments.html">Ornaments</a></li>
              <li><a href="/Woodwork.html">Woodwork</a></li>
              <li><a href="/Radiators.html">Radiators</a></li>
              <li><a href="/luminairy.html">Luminary</a></li>
              <li><a href="/miscellaneous.html">Miscellaneous</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="icon menu-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

EDIT:

```css
.navbar .content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Then I would add two media queries like so :

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    .menu-list li a {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 945px) {
    .menu-list li a {
       font-size: 11.5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,in the other hand the text size also needs to change once it becomes smaller wich in this case doesnt. Overall it seems like nothing has changed since the logo is still getting smaller when tab is reduced and the text keeps its size (it overights it i feel like).

Comment: @Zcel Which text are you referring to? The `nav links` or **text** "Fireplaces, Floorings", etc.. changes from `18px` to `10px` at 800px and below. What is the height and width of your logo? With this information, I can adjust the answer to suit your needs. If you can't provide me with this, can you provide a link to the live ***front-end*** so I can have an accurate version of the issue?

Comment: Im referring to the text "Fireplaces, Floorings", etc.. The dimensions of the logo is 760x260 pixels. Also i think this is the font-end link you were talking about https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?BC6CA245C08F58CC0EC5AFD69A5A33F91F37

Comment: Also by changing the media in the awnser above, the hamburger menu doesnt work annymore

Comment: @Zcel That link was giving me a 404. You can try uploading your files [here](https://bornoe.org/blog/2020/04/tiiny-host-a-free-temporary-static-website-host/) which will give you temporary hosting in which I can see the front-end. Please comment that link once you have done so.